# React Hook Form's register option with 'disabled' works, but 'maxLength' doesn't - Why?

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hook-form, next.js13

I'm using React-Hook-Form, and I passed register to my own component (custom textarea, input .. )
but once I try to pass register with option `{disabled: true, maxLength: 40 }` and check passed register by console but there is only disabled attribute added but no maxLength.

```
{
    "disabled": true
    "name": "test",
    "onBlur" : ...,
    "onChange" : ...,
    "ref" : ... ,

}
```

but I need to use maxLength value which is set in register option.
as I check the type of register return type `UseFormRegisterReturn`  , I could find there is maxLength attribute. but actually it isn't.

I tried to use maxLength in register like this `passedRegister.maxLength` but this is undefined all the time but `passedRegister.disabled` is working well.
not only maxLength most of attributes of register option is not shown.

but I expected to use their value as I set in register option.

here is the code.

```
const TestPage = (props: Props) => {
  const rhf = useForm();
  const testRegister = rhf.register('test', { maxLength: 40, disabled: true });
  return (
    <div className="text-grayscale-130">
      <form>
        <input type="text" {...testRegister} />
        <div>{`maxLength : ${testRegister.maxLength}`}</div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

so here's my question

1. why it is happened?
2. if I can't use maxLength to read then why maxLength is contained in the type `UseFormRegisterReturn` ?
3. how I could use the value which I set as maxLength in register option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. why it is happened?
   Ans: In general testRegister object returned by the ‘register’ function does not include ‘disabled’ or ‘maxlength’ properties. But why disabled is showing in the testRegister object is that disabled is a standard HTML attribute thats why it is coming in the testRegister object. But maxLength is not a standard HTML object thats why it is not showing in the testRegister object. Similarly all the  standard HTML attributes will come in testRegister object like ‘placeholder’, ‘readonly’, ‘required’, ‘value’, ‘checked’ like this. But non standard attributes like ‘bgColor’, ‘maxLength’, ‘border’, ‘align’ will not be included in the testRegister object.
2. how I could use the value which I set as maxLength in register option?

```
function App() {

  const { register } = useForm();
  const maxLength = 40;
  const testRegister = register("test", { disabled: true });

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        {...testRegister}
        maxLength={maxLength}
      />
      <div>MaxLength: {maxLength}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App
```